# Can tamper-resistant blocks be removed by an op?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Can tamper-resistant blocks, such as Warded Blocks, Personal Safes and Trade-O-Mats be removed by a player who is an operator in game? If so, how?

I'm trying to remove a glitched Trade-O-Mat that effectively has no owner. I've tried mining it, turtles, explosions, gravity gun, and so far nothing removes it.

Comment: What about worldedit?

Comment: dang :/ - just cover it up with dirt and pretend it isn't there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorted this by going into creative mode and removing the block from there!

Comment: Why you didn't try this earlier will remain a mystery to me.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the IndustrialCraft wiki](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Personal_Safe):

> After the safe is bound only owner and **server operators may access or use a wrench to remove it.** If you changed your nickname for any reason (starting game in offline mode will change your nick to "Player") you will lose access to the safe.
>   <sub>**Emphasis** mine</sub>

While this is the article for the Personal Safe, one would think that the same mechanics work with the Trade-O-Mat because they are both tamper-resistant blocks.

---

You could also remove it in creative mode. I have never heard of a tamper-resistant block that could not be removed in Creative mode. You could also MCEdit it out or remove it with a mod such as WorldEdit, but the easiest option would probably to cover it up, perhaps with facades (BuildCraft) or panels (RedPower) so that it still looks nice.

Comment: Heck, in creative mode you can remove bedrock!